# Matching the string pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I want to extract all the strings which start with "B" and end with "3". All the strings are available in the file "input.txt".

I used this `sed` command but it's fetching wrong results. can anyone help me in this?

```
sed -n '/^B*3$/p' input.txt
```

**Sample_input:**

```
Boby3
apple2
BUbbly3
Banana3
youas5
BUBLY3
BUb2
```

**Sample_output:**

```
Boby3
BUbbly3
Banana3
BUBLY3
```

Comment: did you mean a line? An ex would be better.

Comment: not matched line. only words. Example Bubbles3, Bob3,

Comment: Edit your question to show a few lines of sample input and expected output.

Comment: @ Ed Morton. Added sample input and sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
grep -oE "\bB[^[:space:]]+3\b" file
```

It will match all characters (including special chars and excluding spaces) between B and 3.

If you want to match word characters only:

```
grep -oE "\bB\w+3\b" file
```

`-o` option is for *only match* (returns only the matched string).

`-E` is for Extended Regex.

Note: Assumed at least one character must be between `B` and `3`. If not (i.e if `B3` should be matched), change the `+` in regex to `*`.

Comment: what is \b used for ?

Comment: @Bubbles Word boundary

Comment: The above won't match the string `B3` - is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @EdMorton I think so... If not then `+` will be replaced with `*`. Edited and added clarification now.

Answer (score 1):

Grep alone be sufficien for extracting words.

```
grep -oP '\bB\w*3\b' file
```

or

```
grep -oP '(?<!\S)B\S*3(?!\S)' file
```

Comment: sorry even that is not fetching result. i am getting NULL set

Comment: Here we go again: `\b` and `\w` are PCRE syntax, `grep` only accepts BRE.